# Dimensionality reduction that preserves non-trivial similarity

Tags: neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction, similarities, embeddings

I have a set of vectors $x_i \in\mathbb{R}^m$ and a similarity function f that quantifies how similar $x_i,x_j$ are. Unfortunately, calculating f takes a lot of time.
I want to use some neural architecture A s.t.:

- $A(x_i)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n<<m$
- Euclidian Distance between $A(x_i),A(x_j)$ will output similar results to f.

When i say similar results i mean that if $A(x_i),A(x_j), A(x_k)$ are embedded in the vector space in a way That $A(x_i),A(x_j)$ are very close to each other but $A(x_k)$ is very far from both, then $f(x_i,x_j)<f(x_i,x_k)$ and $f(x_i,x_j)<f(x_j,x_k)$

What kind of loss should I use for this task?

**Edit**:

The data I have is unlabeled

Comment: This sounds similar to [tag:triplet-loss], but that loss is used for *labeled* data. It's not clear that is what you have here.

Comment: Yeah, I dont have  labels

Comment: Linked to @Syncorax comment, you might like [this](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2003/file/d3b1fb02964aa64e257f9f26a31f72cf-Paper.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @jmarkob!